# adding a library in android studio project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

i couldn't find a way to add this library to my Android Studio project

i need to know where should extract this file

https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line

```
compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.8.4'
```

to build.gradle (Module:app) to make the dependencies section look something like

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.8.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

`compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.8.4'`

on your

build.gradle (Module: app)

in the section of dependencies

Comment: where should i put the downloaded file?